# A special gift perhaps?

Tags: rebus

The answer to this rebus is a 7 word phrase.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my stab at it.

> Eyes in the back of the head?  But I'm not sure why there are upper and lower case 'I's.